# How can I delete my post from the database using a javascript dialog?

Tags: javascript, php, post, dialog

I want to create a dialog so the user can confirm his action if he wants to delete a post. The only problem I am having right now is that if I confirm the dialog, the post with the next ArticleID is being deleted instead of the specific post I wanted to delete. What am I doing wrong or what do I have to add to prevent this bug?

```
$result = $link->query('SELECT * FROM artikel ORDER BY artikelID DESC');
while($record = $result->fetch_array()){

 echo '<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete post?">
</div>';

echo '<div class="artikel" style="clear: both;">
    <a href="?actie=aanpassen&artikelID='.$record['artikelID'].'" id="aanpassenpost"><img src="icons/aanpassen.png" height="15" width="15"></a>
        <img src="icons/delete.png" id="popup" height="15" width="15">
            <script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $("img#popup").click(function(event) {
             $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
              resizable: false,
              height:30,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                  "blabla": function(){
                    location.href = "?actie=verwijderen&artikelID='.$record['artikelID'].'";
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                   },
              Cancel: function() {
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 }
              }
          });
        });
     });
     </script>' ;
    echo'   <h3>'.$record['titel'].'</h3>
        <p>'.$record['inhoud'].'</p>
    </div>';
}
```

This is the code that deletes the posts:

```
if(isset($_GET['actie']) && $_GET['actie'] == "verwijderen"){
$link->query('DELETE FROM artikel WHERE artikelID='.$_GET['artikelID'].';');
```

Comment: What you pasted probably isn't the troublemaker unless there's something weird going on in your DB class. Likewise, we'd like to see how you're handling the call to delete `artikleID`.

Comment: Its because jquery will select the first occurrence of the id found in the dom `id="popup"`, remember you can only have 1 id per document.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are creating a function for each of the records but they are all called by the same thing, so I'd assume the last one would overwrite all the previous ones. You should probably just add some sort of `data-artikelid='<#>'` and then when you open the dialog create the location.href dynamically using `$(this).data('artikelid')`

Answer (score 1):

As stated above. Your jQuery should have one function for the delete dialog, and each delete 'button' should have some sort of data.

```
echo '<img src="icons/delete.png" class="popup" height="15" width="15" data-artikelID=' . $record['artikelID'] . ' />'
```

Then the jQuery function

```
$('img.popup').click(function(event) {
         $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:30,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "blabla": function() {
                  location.href = "?actie=verwijderen&artikelID=" + $(this).data('artikelID');
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               },
          Cancel: function() {
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
             }
          }
      });
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a duplicate script for each button. Also your jQuery selector is identical so the button clicking isn't working how you expect. Try something like this:

What we're doing here is setting a data attribute on the link for the id and then in the jquery script you retrieve it and use it in the redirect link.

```
<?php

$result = $link->query('SELECT * FROM artikel ORDER BY artikelID DESC');

while ($record = $result->fetch_array()) : 

?>

<div class="artikel" style="clear: both;">
    <a href="?actie=aanpassen&artikelID=<?php echo $record['artikelID'] ?>" id="aanpassenpost">
        <img src="icons/aanpassen.png" height="15" width="15">
    </a>
    <img src="icons/delete.png" class="popup" data-artikel-id="<?php echo $record['artikelID'] ?>" height="15" width="15">
    <h3><?php echo $record['titel'] ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $record['inhoud'] ?></p>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>   


<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete post?"></div>


<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $("img.popup").click(function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-artikel-id');

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:30,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "blabla": function(){
                    location.href = "?actie=verwijderen&artikelID=" + id;
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
               },
               Cancel: function() {
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
           }
       });
    });
 });
 </script>
```